# How to pass a form value to a service constructor into an Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I would like to pass a form value to a service to be used in an Observable. How could I pass the name value while the service is being injected in the component? The service has been using environment variables, but I was to customize the name through a form. Thanks!

```
class Component {
    constructor(private myService: MYService){}

    customer: Customer = new Customer();

    updateService(customerForm: NgForm){ ..get it to service 
      customerForm.value.name;        }



class MyService {
   openId: Observable<OpenId>;

 constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router){
    \\ How do I get this.name from component?
    this.openId = this.getOpenID(this.name);
  }

 private getOpenId(name: string): Observable<OpenId>{
   return this.http.get(`${name}`).map(res => res.json()).publishlast().refCount();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already initiated your service in the component's constructor, then you can't just pass a value to the service's constructor later in your component. I think what you need to do is to create a local variable or FormGroup in your component, then sent it to the service by some event like form submit.

#### mycomponent.ts

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component( {
    templateUrl: 'mycomponent.html',
} )

export class MyComponent {
    customerForm : FromGroup;

    constructor(private myService: MyService){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.customerForm = this.formBuilder.group( {
            name : ""
        } );
    }

    // Call this on your form submit, and optionally subscribe to the observable
    updateService() {
        this.myService.getOpenId( this.customerForm.get( "name" ).value ).subscribe( {
            data => {},
            error => {}
        } );
    }
}
```

#### myservice.ts

```
export class MyService {
    constructor(private http: Http){}

    // Make this method publicly accessible, or modify it to suit your need
    getOpenId(name) : Observable<OpenId> {
        return this.http.get(`${name}`).map(res => res.json()).publishlast().refCount();
    }
}
```

Of course, you need your form in the template. Something like this will do:

#### mycomponent.html

```
<form [formGroup]="customerForm" (ngSubmit)="updateService()">
    <input type="text" name="name" formControlName="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I built this example using ReactiveForm because of its flexibility. If you do, make sure you import that in your app.module.

#### app.module.ts

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    ......
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Component. Notice how you subscribe to an Observable exposed by a service

```
class Component {
   customer: Customer = new Customer();
   constructor(private service: Service){}

  updateService(customerForm: NgForm){ 
    this.service.updateService(customerForm.value.name)
      .subscribe(response => response);
  }
}
```

After customizing your name inside your component, you passed it into public method updateService inside your service, after then inside your Service

```
class Service {
  openId: Observable<OpenId>;

  updateService(name: string): Observable<any> { 
    return this.http.get(`${name}`).map(res => 
       res.json()).publishlast().refCount();
  }
}
```